# Probability Product Rule

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

A dangerous computer virus attacks a folder consisting of 250 files. Files are affected by the
virus independently of one another. Each file is affected with the probability 0.032. What
is the probability that more than 7 files are affected by this virus?

---

I was looking at this problem and wondering if the answer to it is simply:

$P = (1 - 0.032^7)$

Comment: No, it is not $1-0.032^7$.  That would be the probability that in a folder consisting of $\color{red}{7}$ files that $\color{red}{\text{less than}}~7$ files were affected by the virus.  For a correct solution, ask yourself... given an integer $k$ between $0$ and $250$, what is the probability that exactly $k$ of the files were affected by the virus?  Use this result and a summation over appropriate values of $k$ to arrive at a final answer.

Comment: For a further hint, the phrase "binomial distribution" should come to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 1 file is affected, there is a 250*.032*(1-.032)^249 probability, since there are 250 different ways that could happen
2 files would be 250*249*.032^2*(1-.032)^248 /2 probability, since there are 250 nCr 2 ways we could do this.

The Odds of any r amount getting the virus would be
$$ \binom{250}{r} * .032^{r} *(1-.032)^{(250-r)} $$
Assuming we're using the nCr Function

Therefore, the odds that at least 7 would get it would be

$$1- \Sigma_{r=0}^7 \binom{250}{r} .032^{r}(1-.032)^{250-r} $$

Which yields us an answer of about 54.931377915%

Comment: This answer is not correct, since the question asks what the probability is of having *more than 7* files affected by the virus.

Comment: True.  Hold on, let me fix this real quick.

Comment: It is also recommended to use `\binom{n}{r}` instead of `~_{n}C_{r}` for binomial coefficients here as the former is a much more widespread and recognizable notation than the latter.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks. It's kinda hard getting used to all the symbols here

Comment: One more minor error which you edited in after I had last looked, you used the word "odds" instead of probability.  Odds and probability are related concepts, but distinctly different.  Having a probability of success of $\frac{1}{10}$ corresponds to an odds of success of $1:9$.  Try not to confuse the terms and use one where you should have used the other.

Answer (score 2):

this is a classic binomial probability distribution question. You're asking to choose r from n with success & failure. Hence:

```
n=250 (number of trials) 
r=7 (number of success or more)
p=0.032 (will be effected; probability of success in a signal trial)
q=1-.032=0.968 (will not be effected)
```

since you're looking for

> more than 7

we're looking for the **cumulative probability** of P(x>7) so if we use the nice equation of Math Machine you'll get 0.549313779150176

[When to use the binomial distribution (Yale University):](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/binom.htm)

```
1: The number of observations n is fixed.
2: Each observation is independent.
3: Each observation represents one of two outcomes ("success" or "failure").
4: The probability of "success" p is the same for each outcome.
```